# Simple HTML DOM outputs the 'wrong' hierarchy

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Im scraping with simple html dom and would like to scrape `div`, `span` and `img` so I do:

```
$c = $html->find('div, span, img');
echo $c->outertext;
```

This gives me the output as it is on the page, so the elements are mixed up as they appear on the scraped page: div img img img span span img div span etc.

Is there a way to get the output like the PHP statement? So first all the `div` and then all the `span` and last all the `img` without multiple calls to the PHP file of course.

Comment: I just realized I could do "find() and echo" for every element but Im working with variables and would like to keep the "find" function as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(array('div', 'span', 'img') as $name){
  $c = $html->find($name);
  echo $c->outertext;
}
```